# postman test data type of the response

Tags: json, testing, postman

Hi i try to run a postman test where i would check if the json data is equal to integer.

i tried to run this

```
{   
    "passagiersnummer": 2021,  
    "naam": "klaas van buren"
}
```

and for the test

```
pm.test("Test data type of the response", function () {
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.expect(jsonData.passagiersnummer).to.be.a("number");
pm.expect(jsonData.naam).to.be.a("string");
});
```

test result:

```
FAIL | Test data type of the response | AssertionError: expected undefined to be a number
```

what do i do wrong and how can i fix this issue.

Comment: I've tested your code. Nothing wrong. `expected undefined to be a number` means there is no `passagiersnummer` in the response, double check the response first.

Comment: Show your response

Comment: my response is just 2021

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
`const jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.test("Test data type of the response", () => {
pm.expect(jsonData.passagiersnummer).to.be.a("number");
pm.expect(jsonData.naam).to.be.a("string");
});`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to parseInt the jsonData.passagiersnummer. It will parse the string and return the integer

```
pm.test("Test data type of the response", function () {
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.expect(parseInt(jsonData.passagiersnummer)).to.be.a("number");
pm.expect(jsonData.naam).to.be.a("string");
});
```